# Unity 5.4 - broken serialization

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine, beta

It seems as if Unity 5.4 has a serialization issue:

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private MyObject obj;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyObject¨
{
}
```

results in :

```
InvalidOperationException: The operation is not possible when moved past all properties (Next returned false)
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it in Unity 5.3? Also, I think serialization of privates is not standard behavior. Use [SerializeField] there.

Comment: Actually, I added it. If I remove it, it allows to display but will fail when trying Debug mode for Inspector. I have not tried in 5.3 but I have been using before, I just move there for Hololens.

Comment: Maybe put some public stuff in MyObject? It looks so empty inside so there's nothing to serialize there...

Comment: OK that was it...thanks. Convert to answer.

Comment: In general, Serialization in Unity is a joke.  I just wouldn't bother.  It's rarely needed, or useful, in real-world games.

Comment: @JoeBlow in 95% cases true, but it is very useful in Editor Scripts and plugins.

Comment: a good point, Jerry

Comment: I actually use Deserialization a lot to read in JSON data files. And occasionally also Serialization to write settings files. Works good enough for simple things, and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put some public fields in the class you want to serialize. If it's empty, or only has private or protected fields, there's nothing to serialize.
The error message could have been better (something like "nothing to serialize" instead of the one you're getting).

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue when using the debug Inspector and disabling it and just using the normal Inspector cleared the error. My guess is it has something to do with the private fields being visible like Serialized Fields.